# How to create a join table record

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So I'm trying to add a record to my join table, but it doesn't seem to work, no errors are given either.

So here's my data array (which saves correctly without a problem)

```
array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "32"
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "Hello"
    ["participant"]=>
    array(1) {
    [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(1)
        }
      }
}
```

My belongs to many:

```
$this->belongsToMany('Participants', [
        'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'participant_id',
        'className' => 'Users',
        'joinTable' => 'participants_items'
    ]);
```

Belongs to many in my Users:

```
$this->belongsToMany('myItems', [
        'foreignKey' => 'participant_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'item_id',
        'className' => 'Items',
        'joinTable' => 'participants_items'
    ]);
```

The following methods I've tried to apply a join table record:

```
$data['Participants'] = [ //Also tried Participant, participants, participant
    ['id' => 1]
];
```

And also:

```
$data['Participants'] = [
    '_ids' => [1, 2]
];
```

What am I doing wrong? I get no errors & no entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that my mistake actually was in the newEntity() part!

Before(Broken): `$newEntity = $this->newEntity($inputData]);`

After(Fixed): `$newEntity = $this->newEntity($inputData, ['associated' => ['Participants']])`

And BEFORE executing newEntity I add the id's to the data list as following:

```
$inputData['participants'] = [
    '_ids' => [10, 12]
];
```